# Что значить params int[] nums

Tags: c#

```
class Min
{
    public int MinVal(params int[] nums)
    {
        int m;

        if (nums.Length == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: no arguments.");
            return 0;
        }

        m = nums[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < nums.Length; i++)
            if (nums[i] < m) m = nums[i];

        return m;
    }
}
```

Не понял в этой строчке `public int MinVal(params int[] nums)`. Объявляется метод MinVal которое должен возвращать значения типа int. Тут `(params int[] nums)`. `params` - это модификатор, `int[] num` - что тут происходит и как понять это?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это значит, что метод может принимать 0 и больше элементов типа `int`, либо же массив `int`'ов.
Например, она может быть вызвана так:

```
MinVal(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

или так:

```
MinVal(1, 2)
```

Подробнее на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w5zay9db.aspx)