# Вариативный параметр в методе C#

Tags: c#, .net, методы

Реально ли создать метод с вариативным параметром, который можно не указывать?

```
static double Discriminant(double a, double b, double c, double d)
{
    d = (b * b) - 4 * a * c;
    return d;
}
```

Это метод подсчета дискриминанта

```
double QE = Discriminant(a: 23, b: 15, c: 12);
```

Это переменная, которой присваивается значение, которое считает вышеуказанный метод. Но задав d мы распечатываем, не то что мы посчитали, а то что мы задали. В этом и проблема

Comment: Подойдёт такой вариант `double Discriminant(double a, double b, double c = null, double d = null)`? Ну и [классический пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/516410/213987) `public static void Program(params object[] args)`

Comment: Можно сделать перегрузку метода.

Comment: @AK первый вариант не подходит, а второй, возможен, но в другом случае, сейчас необходимо справится без (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/516410/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-params-int-nums)

Comment: @SuperMario Тогда перегрузите метод, как советует Назар.

Comment: а в чем смысл параметра `d`??? он нигде не используется

Comment: Хотя вот я так смотрю на отформатированную версию кода и недоумеваю: а что вы хотели сделать и зачем это понадобилось? У вас d задаётся на вводе и одновременно считается.

Comment: @AK Хах, точно ведь, можно просто объявить ее в методе не передавая. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Есть три варианта:

1. `double Discriminant(double a, double b, double? c = null, double? d = null)`?
2. `public static void Program(params object[] args)` (схожий вопрос [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/516410/213987))
3. Перегрузка метода.

PS Зачем вам вообще d? Можно написать проще:

```
static double Discriminant(double a, double b, double c)
{
    return (b * b) - 4 * a * c;
}

double QE = Discriminant(a: 23, b: 15, c: 12);
```

Насчёт:

> точно ведь, можно просто объявить ее в методе не передавая.

Эта переменная используется менее двух раз (не нужна для дальнейших расчётов), её можно не объявлять. Удобство разве что для отладки.

Comment: в первом варианте должно быть `double? d = null` для `c` аналогично

Comment: @rdorn Вот что значит писать код не в IDE, а сразу в комментарии )) Спасибо за уточнение.